# Mustn't both left and right inverses be checked?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Source: [*Linear Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321385179) by Lay (4 edn 2011). p. 160. Chapter 2 Supplementary Exercise 4.

> **Exercise:** Suppose $A^n = 0$ matrix for some $n > 1$. Find an inverse for $I - A$.
>
> **Solution:** From p. 160 Supplementary Exercise 3, the inverse of $I-A$ is probably $I+A+A^{2}+...+A^{n-1}$. To verify this, compute
>   $ (I \color{orangered}{-A} )\color{forestgreen}{(I+A+\cdots+A^{n-1})}=I+A+\cdots+A^{n-1} \quad \color{orangered}{-A}(I+A+\cdots+A^{n-1})=I \color{orangered}{-A} A^{n-1}=I-A^{n}.
> $
>   If $A^{n}=0$, then the above equation becomes $(I-A)\color{forestgreen}{\sum_{0 \le i \le n - 1} A^{i}} =...=I$. Since $I-A$ and $\sum_{0 \le i \le n - 1} A^{i} $ are square, they are invertible by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, and $\sum_{0 \le i \le n - 1} A^{i} $ is the inverse of $I-A$. $\blacksquare$
>
> [image]

$1.$ The definition of inverse overhead (from Lay p. 103) contains two conjuncts.
Why didn't the solution fail to check that $\color{forestgreen}{\sum_{0 \le i \le n - 1} A^{i}}$ is the left inverse? Why only check it as the right inverse?

$2.$ Why didn't Lay define with only one of the right or left inverse, because [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/53259) guarantees the other inverse? Is Lay's definition with two conjuncts/inverses redundant?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, if $A$ is a square matrix then $AC=I\iff CA=I$. So, once you have left/right inverse for $A$, then you will have the other one.

Comment: square *finite* matrix.

Comment: Yes, indeed. As I know, if one says a square matrix then I'll think it is a finite matrix.

Comment: You're wellcome :D

Comment: Thank you again. Would you mind advising me about my new question 2 (which just entered my mind) in your answer, and not as comments?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that some care is needed.

For finite matrices, existence of left inverse implies invertibility, and existence of a right inverse implies invertibility. It is not very hard to show these claims but certainly if it was not established then you need to verify on both sides. In this particular case, the verification is essentially identical to the one given, and I guess that is why this detail was omitted. But you are correct, there is something else to say here.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much! I just removed my question 2 here and posted a new question for it at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/795755/53259. Would you mind moving your answer for 2 over there and deleting it here (while keeping 1) ?

Comment: you are most welcome, and I did as you requested.

Comment: Thank you again. Would you mind advising me about my new question 2 (which just entered my mind) in your answer, and not as comments? I've un-accepted the answer for now, so that I know that I haven't apprehended this fully.