# A criterion for invertibility of a bounded linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I'm studying Semigroup Theory and I wasn't able to understand a step in a certain proof. As far as I have been able to understand, the author used the following result:

If $A$ is a bounded linear operator and $\|A-I\|<1,$ then $A$ is invertible.

Is it true? If it is true, how can I prove it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/795759/27978.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true, provable as follows:  for any operator $B$ with $\Vert B \Vert < 1$, $I - B$ is invertable since

$(I - B)(\sum_0^n B^k) = I - B^{n + 1}; \tag{1}$

now note that $\Vert B \Vert < 1$ implies

$\Vert B^n \Vert \le \Vert B \Vert^n \to 0 \tag{2}$

as $n \to \infty$;  thus

$B^n \to 0 \tag{3}$

as $n \to \infty$ as well.  Letting $n$ increase without bound in (1) thus yields

$(I - B)(\sum_0^\infty B^k) = I; \tag{4}$

that is, $I - B$ is invertible with inverse $\sum_0^\infty B^k$.

Taking $B  = I - A$ establishes the result.

***Note Added Sunday 10 May 2015 11:10 AM PST:***  It's probably not a bad idea, for the sake of completeness, to flesh things out just a ***tad*** and show explicitly that $\sum_0^\infty B^k$ converges, although I think this might follow from the above without further words on the matter.  Nevertheless, setting

$S_n = \sum_0^n B^k \tag{5}$

we have for $m > n$

$\Vert S_m - S_n \Vert = \Vert \sum_{n + 1}^m B^k \Vert =  \Vert B^{n + 1}\sum_0^{m - n - 1} B^k \Vert \le \Vert B \Vert^{n + 1} \Vert \sum_0^{m - n - 1} B^k \Vert$
$\le  \Vert B \Vert^{n + 1}(\sum_0^{m - n -1} \Vert B \Vert^k) \le \Vert B \Vert^{n + 1} (\sum_0^\infty \Vert B \Vert^k) = \dfrac{\Vert B \Vert^{n + 1}}{1 - \Vert B \Vert}, \tag{6}$

where $\sum_0^\infty \Vert B \Vert^k$ converges, and is equal to $(1 - \Vert B \Vert)^{-1}$, since $\Vert B \Vert < 1$; it is a real geometric series with ratio $\Vert B \Vert$.  Lettting $n \to \infty$ then shows that $S_n$ is Cauchy etc. etc. etc.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Morning. Mother's day precludes the Med.

Comment: @copper.hat:  and a jolly good Mother's Day Morn to you, sir!  Being my own mother, and a ***real mother*** to boot, I am celebrating myself by myself.  Not at the Med (the scene on Telegraph has gotten too crazy even for my eclectic tastes), but at a cute little spot called Earthly Coffee at 55th and MLK.  Know the spot or the 'hood?  Check it out sometime!  Strong Coffee, Good Food!  Cheers!

Comment: Will try your recommendation! My backup is Espresso Roma Cafe opposite Monterey Market.

Comment: I'll have to check that place out!

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the fact that if $|x|<1$ then $1+x+x^2+\cdots = {1 \over 1-x}$.

Let $y=x-1$ to get
$1+(1-y)+(1-y)^2+\cdots = {1 \over y}$.

Write $A=I +(A-I)$, and look at the series $I+(A-I)+(A-I)^2+\cdots$. Show that this converges and the result equals $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Short lived acceptance...

Comment: Be consoled, I know the feeling.  In Love and Math, acceptance is often short lived!  Once again, a Good Mother's Day to You, Sir!

Comment: Mathematics is a cruel mistress, but at least it exists :-).

Comment: Indeed:  cruel, but with more staying power then so many of those others . . . ah well, I regret not the departure of so many of them! ;-)

Comment: For Mother, ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$